# decltype: Access static member of class using a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, decltype

I have a templated function `f`. I am passing it either a reference or a pointer to an object. That object is of struct `S`. I would like to know the size of `S::my_tuple`, which is a static member of that struct.

I can do that when I pass the object by reference with `std::tuple_size<decltype(T::my_tuple)>::value`.

How can I do this for a pointer? This currently fails, since `my_tuple` is not a member of `S*`

[Play with the code](https://godbolt.org/z/VEAsYi).

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct S {
  constexpr static auto my_tuple = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 4);
};


template <typename T>
int f(const T object) {

  // fails if T is a pointer
  if (std::is_pointer<T>::value) {
    // error
    return std::tuple_size<decltype(T::my_tuple)>::value;
   }

    // works if T is a reference
    return std::tuple_size<decltype(T::my_tuple)>::value;
}

int main() {
    S my_struct;
    std::cout << f(my_struct); // 4, correct size of properties 
    S* my_ptr = new S;
    std::cout << f(my_ptr); // does not compile
}
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the support. Here is the [solution](https://godbolt.org/z/IoGuaN)

Comment: You don't really need branches in this particular case. Just use `return std::tuple_size_v<decltype(std::remove_pointer_t<T>::my_tuple)>;` as **cigien** suggests in his answer. Removing pointer from a non-pointer type won't hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove pointer with a [type trait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer):

```
decltype(std::remove_pointer_t<std::decay_t<T>>::my_tuple)
```

In `const T object`, `T` is never a reference. `std::decay_t<T>` is needed if you use, for example, a universal reference (`T&& object`) instead.

Also note that all branches of your code should compile when you use `if`. If you want to discard a branch based on `std::is_pointer_v<T>`, take a look at [constexpr `if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If):

```
if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>) {
    // ...
} else {
    // this code can be invalid if T is a pointer
}
```

Something like

```
if (std::is_pointer_v<T>)
    return std::tuple_size_v<decltype(std::remove_pointer_t<T>::my_tuple)>;
else
    return std::tuple_size_v<decltype(T::my_tuple)>;
```

will not work in general.

In your particular example you can just always remove pointer, because if `T` is not a pointer type, `std::remove_pointer_t<T>` is `T` itself:

```
template <typename T>
std::size_t f(T&&) {
    using Tuple = decltype(std::remove_pointer_t<std::decay_t<T>>::my_tuple);
    return std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>;
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Can you add a version that works with both reference and pointer?

Comment: @User12547645, we can use `std::decay` to handle references and arrays, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a type trait to get the type pointed at by the pointer, like this:

```
template <typename T>
int f(const T object) {
    return std::tuple_size_v<decltype(std::remove_pointer_t<T>::my_tuple)>;
}
```

This will handle the case of a reference, or a pointer, in the same expression.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rmto4u).

Comment: Amazing. Can you add a version that works with both reference and pointer?

Comment: This answer does that. Did you click on the demo, and try it out?